# 000webhost unicode issue in website

Tags: php, html, unicode

I am new in 000webhost. Recently I have uploaded a website (built in using php and html) in the file manager. In every webpage, I used meta charset="UTF-8". When I go to any page, the texts that are of unicodes are not shown, instead they are shown as undesired symbols. I have tried the solution given [here](https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-fix-the-character-set-charset-issue/62722) but it does not work. Current output is:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iup95.png)

But the expected output should be:
[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwLvn.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In phpMyAdmin, change your column's collation attribute's value into utf8mb4_unicode_ci or any other unicode font. This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked for me like a charm!